# Numerical solution of non-linear diffusion equation via finite-difference with the Crank-Nicolson method

Tags: finite-difference, parabolic-pde, nonlinear-equations, diffusion

I want to numerically solve the non-linear diffusion equation:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} T(x,t)= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(T^{5/2} \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \right)
$$

I want to use finite difference approach to solve it via Crank-Nicolson method. But I don't understand how to treat the non-linear coefficient when applying the numerical method.

Comment: Please specify the boundary conditions you wish to implement.

Answer (score 4):

The Crank-Nicolson discretization of this equation will read
$$
  \frac{T^n-T^{n-1}}{\Delta t} = \frac 12 \left[
    \partial_x \left((T^n)^{5/2} \partial_x T^n\right)
    +
    \partial_x \left((T^{n-1})^{5/2} \partial_x T^{n-1}\right)
\right]
$$
which is a nonlinear, time-independent, elliptic partial differential equation in $T^n$. The way to solve such equations is summarized in step-15 of the deal.II tutorial, see http://www.dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/step_15.html .

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of deal.II, and I supervised the student who wrote step-15.)

Comment: Dear Wolfgang, I need to communicate with you via email. I have some questions.

Comment: @user4624; I'm easy to find on the internet. Send me an email.