# Numerical solution of non-linear heat-diffusion PDE using the Crank-Nicolson Method

Tags: pde, finite-difference, nonlinear-equations, crank-nicolson

I am trying to solve numerically the following 1D EBM:

$C\frac{\partial T[x,t] }{\partial t} - \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left ( D(1-x^2)\frac{\partial T[x,t] }{\partial x} \right ) + I[T] = S[x,t](1-A[T])$

where $C$ and $D$ are constants.

I want to use the Crank-Nicolson method to solve it but I am unsure how to implement it with all of the non-linear terms.

What would the Crank-Nicolson discretization of this equation be?

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7780/numerical-solution-of-non-linear-diffusion-equation-via-finite-difference-with-t?rq=1 can't this help? what is A[T] and I[T] btw?

Comment: What does EBM stands for?

Comment: The C-N discretization will simply yield a nonlinear differential equation at each time step. You then need to solve it using something like a Newton method.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I think you mean "a nonlinear system of algebraic equations".

Comment: @DavidKetcheson, well that depends on whether you discretize first in time then space, or the other way around :-)

Answer (score 1):

Anyone still interested in an answer, see this article:

[P. Y. P. Chen and B. A. Malomed, "Lanczos-Chebyshev pseudospectral methods for wave-propagation problems," *Mathematics Computers Simulation*, vol. 82, no. 6, pp. 1056–1068, Feb. 2012.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.matcom.2011.05.013)

In this published method, Crank-Nicholson forward difference method is used with an inner iterative step to cater for the nonlinear terms.